# jQuery Queue, how to create queue for notice system

Tags: jquery, scripting, notice

I created a simple jQuery script, that's displays notification for users.
This script is available on: `jsfiddle.net/vLqQF/`

I want to create queue, if I run 5 notice in short time, users dosnt see them. It's only working if prev is complete and hidden.
I'm trying do a simple queue for that, but it seems to be more complicated.
Anybody could help me?

Comment: Take a look at [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q)

Comment: you can add the queue like this [http://jsfiddle.net/vLqQF/5/](http://jsfiddle.net/vLqQF/5/)

Comment: Abraham Urible, very thanks! This is exactly what I want to do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at setInterval().  You can call your action and specify a time to wait:

```
var interval = setInterval(function(){
    notice(1,1,'Hello World2');
}, 2000);
```

Then to clear the interval just use

```
clearInterval(interval);
```

This will clear the interval when you click the div

Updated your fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/vLqQF/4/

Comment: Remove the parens from `someAction()`.

Comment: But if I want to change action to: Close on click, then interval is not good idea

Comment: Sorry not sure what you mean but if you want the user to stop the process you can use clearInterval.  See updated fiddle.  When a user clicks the div the process will stop (close).